# Not all rows are imported to MySQL workbench from CSV file?

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, mysql-workbench, import-csv

I’m a new SQL learner and I’m having problems while trying to import CSV file into MySQL Workbench.

The CSV file has 541909 Rows but when it is imported into MySQL, only around 35000 rows are imported and I knew the number difference by using the COUNT command.

No error is shown during the import process and I even changed to 1000000 limit rows in the preference setting. I’m using MacBook.

Below is my table query and link to my CSV file

https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00352/

(Original file is xlsx but I changed it to a CSV file)

Link for the cdv is
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EyZ9JrlsXcAxQz5BdAXTDVYjSLy25ZWOE1fpv0jDjxM/edit?usp=sharing

yet it only imports 76318 rows out of over 500,000 rows. That's why I am stuck. Here is csv link docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/

Any idea of resolving this issue is highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE Online_Retail (
    InvoiceNo   VARCHAR(100),
    Stock_Code  VARCHAR(50),
    Description TEXT,
    Quantity DECIMAL,
    Invoice_Date DATE,
    Unit_Price  DECIMAL,
    Customer_ID VARCHAR(50),
    Country VARCHAR(100)
);
```

Comment: Can you share the `count()` query you use (just to double check).

Comment: your linked file is a excel file no csv, even converted workbench doesn't like the date format. wich needs to be yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM:ss

Comment: @JNevill Hello this is my query. SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Online_Retail;

Comment: @nbk I mentioned that the file is converted to CSV. Also dates were formatted as you said.

Comment: @Irene wy didn't you post the csv in your link, mysql workbench shows a log when there is a problem it should show the problem he as, so you can look for the probolem and fix it

Comment: and @JNevill want to know the number not the query

Comment: @nbk No error is shown in mysql workbench log yet it only imports 76318 rows out of over 500,000 rows. That's why I am stuck. Here is csv link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EyZ9JrlsXcAxQz5BdAXTDVYjSLy25ZWOE1fpv0jDjxM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @JNevill only 76318 rows are imported.

Comment: The link is to a spreadsheet not a csv file. Anyways imports often 'fail' because terminator is not defined correctly on import - what did you define it as, \n , \r\n or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Posting the answer late for others facing the problem. I would not suggest to use the MYSQL workbench import wizard, it doesn't tell the errors. I tried removing commas, any spaces but didn't solve the problem.

The easiest way is

1. Convert CSV to .sql file using any online convertor like convertcsv.com (For convertcsv.com enter table name, ignore output options, keep all default options checked). Finally do a quick check on Step 4: Generate output to see if it is inserting into the right table)
2. Import using command line mysql -u  -p  < filename.sql